# Create a PriorityQueue that contains triples, and returns the minimum third element in Scala?

Tags: scala, priority-queue

I have a Priority Queue in Scala that I define below. My goal is that when I call dequeue I get the triple that has the most minimum third element in that triple. I figured that using Ordering is the way to go, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue

def orderByWeight(lst : (Int, Int, Int)) = lst._3

val pq = new PriorityQueue[(Int, Int, Int)]()(Ordering.by(orderByWeight))

var x = ListBuffer((0,1,2), (0,2,3), (0,3,4))

x.map(i => pq.enqueue(i))
```

I am confused on what my `orderByWeight` function should be. For the code above, the desired output if I call `pq.dequeue` should be `(0, 1, 2)`. Note `x` is ordered at random. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the 3-tuples dequeued in order of smalled 3rd element to largest, I think this is all you need.

```
val pq = PriorityQueue[(Int, Int, Int)]()(Ordering.by(-_._3))
```

If you need an ordered output in case of 3rd-element ties, you can expand it.

```
var x = ListBuffer((0,1,2), (0,2,3), (0,3,4), (1,0,2))
val pq = PriorityQueue(x:_*)(Ordering[(Int, Int)].on(x => (-x._3, -x._2)))
```